# Create Azure web site with Django and postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have django + postgresql web site.

I want publish them to Azure web site.

How I can sync db, or create postgresql database in azure web site?

If I can do it, what I need write in settings file?

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'xxx',
            'USER': 'xxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
            'HOST': 'xxx',
            #'PORT': 'xxx',
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no build-in postgre in Azure App Service. you will have to point your app to a remote database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish your app to Azure App Service (web apps, formerly web sites, is within the App Service). However, you won't be able to install postgres there. Instead, you'll need to install that to a VM (or use a 3rd-party postgresql hoster).